# Choose the starting cell of a do-loop

Tags: excel, vba

I want to start a loop mid column (Row 15 let's say).

Current code (part of a much larger script)

```
Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R15C3"

Dim BlankFound As Boolean
Dim x As Long

'Loop until a blank cell is found in Column C
  Do While BlankFound = False
    x = x + 1

    If Cells(x, "C").Value = "" Then
      BlankFound = True
    End If
  Loop
```

I tried changing the column ref (C) to a cell (C15). I tried to specify the start and end point (C15:C).

We have a client order form that when they click a button converts to another format ready to be uploaded. The client will fill out various fields that populate rows 1 and 2 (name, address, etc.), then from row three it is the number of orders, i.e.

row
3  part number     quantity    availability
4  part number     quantity    availability

I want it to look at the original form and only populate down if it finds a value in the original form's cell.

Then at the end I have another row to add, so I need to be able to say when this loop finishes, add these values (these are just an extra row of totals and some formatting).

The full code-

```
Sub ButtonMacroLatest()
'Hide alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'
' Macro8 Macro
'

'Save to users device
    ChDir "U:\WINDOWS"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="U:\WINDOWS\OrderForm.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

'Create new workbook and populate
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "MSG"
    Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R[1]C"
    Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R[1]C[3]"
    Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "1400008000"
    Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "501346009175"
    Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "=TODAY()"
    Range("G1").FormulaR1C1 = "=Now()"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-x-systime]h:mm:ss AM/PM"
    Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "HDR"
    Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "C"
    Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R4C2"
    Range("G2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R[1]C[3]"
    Range("H2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R2C4"
    Range("K2").FormulaR1C1 = "STD"
    Range("L2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R5C2"
    Range("N2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R7C2"
    Range("O2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R8C2"
    Range("Q2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R9C2"
    Range("R2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R12C2"
    Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "POS"
    Range("B3").FormulaR1C1 = "=Row()*10-20"
    Range("C3").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R15C3"
Dim BlankFound As Boolean
Dim x As Long

'Loop until a blank cell is found in Column C
  Do While BlankFound = False
    x = 14
    x = x + 1

    If Cells(x, "C").Value = "" Then
      BlankFound = True
    End If
  Loop

    Range("D3").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R15C1"
    Range("E3").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R15C2"
    Range("F3").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R15C5"
    Range("G3").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R15C7"

    'Preformat cells to remove 0 value
    Range("A1:AP1000").Select
    Range("AP1000").Activate
    Selection.NumberFormat = "#;#;"

    Range("H3").FormulaR1C1 = "GBP"
    Range("L3").FormulaR1C1 = "TRA"
    Range("M3").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C[-3], ""POS"")+COUNTIF(C[-3], ""HDR"")"


'Reinstate alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

In the client facing form A15:C15 are material/part numbers. If populated those rows should fill down in the new form until there is no entry in the original form.

Customer form
[image: Customer form]

Comment: Why not `x=15` before your loop?

Comment: maybe put `x=14` above `Do While BlankFound = False` ...?

Comment: Nope, didn't work. It puts in the first value but still doesn't loop through.

Comment: What happened if you press `F8` to see how it goes?

Comment: As the script is based on the open doc you can't F8 through as it throws up an error that the doc is open.

Comment: As soon as a blank cell is found your loop is exited.

Comment: I know, that's the whole point of the question. It's starting the loop mid column, so there is blanks to begin with that will always be blank. How do I start from C15 and loop until blank?.

Comment: Then give `x` an initial value like `14` as @Jeeped said.

Comment: newacc2240 I tried it earlier, it still only populates the first cell, it doesn't pull down.

Comment: We've told you. If it's not working there is another issue, eg a cell looks blank but isn't.

Comment: "it still only populates the first cell, it doesn't pull down". This is confusing, there is nothing in your code which would pull anything down and your loop doesn't populate anything.

Comment: Hi SJR, this is what I'm asking for. I have some code, it doesn't work. I can't find what I need elsewhere and everything I have tried doesn't work. So, again, my question. How do I start at c15 and loop until blank. Let's say this is your sporeadsheet and it references a cell in another form that you only want to pull through if it is populated (ie no zero value), then how would you do it and then copy that down until blank?.  I don't think I can be much clearer (due to my level of knowledge). Start at C15, copy down until blank, that's all I need to know how to do.

Comment: As has been said - for the code you've given the value of `x` needs to be changed to 14 just before it goes into the `Do While....`.  If this isn't happening then you've missed the bit of code that's making that not happen.... can you post _all_ the relevant code please.

Comment: "copy down until blank" - what are you copying down? In your loop why not check if it's blank, if it is exit, if not copy from whichever cell you want to copy from. So you add an Else to your If.

Comment: Maybe there's one missing bit of information - you put the formula into cell C2, but that formula is looking at `C15`  on the `Order` sheet in the `OrderForm` file.  Do you want to find the first blank on the `Order` sheet after cell `C15`?  So `C3` on the activesheet is referencing `Order!C16`, `C4` is looking at `Order!C17` and so on?

Comment: Yup you got it Darren. I've just posted the full code on my original post as not to put it in the notes. Please feel free to pick it apart if there is a better way. In essence I have two title rows and then an order list that needs to populate as you've described. After that there is a totals row which I can add later on.  I can add the original form and post form formatting if needed?.

Comment: Good stuff - all updates to the question should go in as edits.  The first thing is you've put `x=14` after `Do While....` - it's getting reset to 14 every pass of the loop so will always appear on line 15.  Put it before that line and should be good to go (except you're not being specific about which book & sheet to put formula on).

Comment: So this is where my knowledge fails me. I have moved the x value to the line before "Do While BlankFound = False" as mentioned earlier. Still only populates line one (C3) on the workbook "orderform" sheet "order". I have populated the fields in the original form to be sure, but they still don't pull through. Is the code any good at all, or is there a better way?.

Comment: Added thge original customer form for your ease, it might be a bit clearer.

Comment: It should be populating the new un-named workbook with values taken from `[OrderForm.xlsx]Order` sheet not putting values onto the `Order` sheet.

Comment: It may infact be made all the more difficult by how I have started it. In order to make things easier it dumps a copy to the temp folder (or it will when the file path is updated after testeing), once it is there the original file name doesn't exist, it becomes orderform.xlsx, I then use the short paths as the doc is open. Perhaps this may be part of why it's not so straight forward??? Again, limited knowledge so just throwing out ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took something a lot simpler, it works a treat for what I need. Code:

```
'Fills column to last row of data from Cell C15
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Range("C15:C" & LastRow).FillDown
    Range("D15:D" & LastRow).FillDown
    Range("E15:E" & LastRow).FillDown
```

Thanks for all of the responses.

Comment: You may want to put the FIND into a range first - if the sheet is empty it will return Nothing which you can't get the row number from (so will throw an error). Set it to a range, check that it's not nothing and then get the row number. Set FoundRange=Cells.Find.... & If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to figure out exactly where you're grabbing values from and where you're putting them, but hopefully this bit of code will give you enough ideas to get yours sorted.

```
Public Sub ButtomMacroLatest()

    Dim wrkBk As Workbook
    Dim wbOF As Workbook
    Dim shtCSV As Worksheet
    Dim shtOF As Worksheet
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim x As Long, y As Long

    'OrderForm is closed so needs opening:
    'Set wbOF = Workbooks.Open("U:\.......\OrderForm.xlsx")

    'OrderForm is the workbook containing this code:
    Set wbOF = ThisWorkbook

    'Set a reference to the "Order" sheet and
    'find the last row - based on column A being populated.
    Set shtOF = wbOF.Worksheets("Order")
    lLastRow = shtOF.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Create workbook with 1 sheet and set reference to that sheet.
    Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    Set shtCSV = wrkBk.Worksheets(1)

    'Add headings to the sheet.
    shtCSV.Range("A1:G1") = Array("MSG", "SomeHeading", "SomeOtherHeading", "1400008000", _
                                  "501346009175", Date, Now)

    'Copy values in cell "A15:J<LastRow>" to "A2" on the new sheet.
    With shtOF
        'Straight copy
        '.Range(.Cells(15, 1), .Cells(lLastRow, 10)).Copy _
            Destination:=shtCSV.Range("A2")

        'Paste Special
        .Range(.Cells(15, 1), .Cells(lLastRow, 10)).Copy
        With shtCSV.Range("A2")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        End With

        'Make the value of one cell equal the value of another cell
        'in a loop from row 15 to LastRow and column 1 to 10.
        'For x = 15 To lLastRow
        '    For y = 1 To 10
        '        shtCSV.Cells(x - 13, y) = .Cells(x, y)
        '    Next y
        'Next x

    End With

    wrkBk.SaveAs Environ("temp") & "/CSV File.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```